# remove loading gif after window.location has returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am downloading a file I create on the server on a button click as in the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#reportBtn').on('click', function() {
    $('#loadingScreen').removeClass('hidden');
    window.location = '/myApp/Home/GenerateReport';
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#loadingScreen').addClass('hidden');
    }, 20000);
  });
});
```

It works fine and I know that ideally this should really be wrapped in an AJAX call and return a unique GUID and return the file that way - however I cant use that approach and I am just wondering is there a better way I should be detected when the file has downloaded so I can remove the loading gif better.  I have hard coded the 20 seconds which I know isnt really correct - sometimes depending on the amount of data in the report it downloads in 10 seconds or it could take 30 seconds to download.

Is there a better approach I could use keeping the fundamental call to window.location the same - note this is an MVC call which returns a FileResult of `return File(data, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, reportName);`

Comment: Look at [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) once. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this, you can try another approach for displaying a **loading spinner** i.e. during page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {  
            var form = $("#frmCreate");
            form.validate();

            if (form.valid()) {  
                $("#loading").fadeIn();
                var opts = {
                    lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
                    length: 7, // The length of each line
                    width: 4, // The line thickness
                    radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
                    color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
                    speed: 1, // Rounds per second
                    trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
                    shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
                    hwaccel: false // Whether to use hardware acceleration
                };
                var target = document.getElementById('loading');
                var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
            }
        });  
    });
</script>


<div id="loading">
    <div id="loadingcontent">
        <p id="loadingspinner">
            Loading...
        </p>
    </div>
</div>   
 
 
<style>
    #loading {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        z-index: 1000;
    }
 
    #loadingcontent {
        display: table;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
 
    #loadingspinner {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: larger;
        padding-top: 80px;
    }
</style>
```

Similarly you can also use some plugin in order to display loading spinner.